# Image editors to convert images to WebP for Ubuntu?

Tags: editor, photo, webp

Is there a good image editor application for Ubuntu with which I can convert jpg/png images into WebP format? ImageMagick was a crap for me! With it, output webp image's size just increased!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a plugin for [the Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) that provides the ability to load and export WebP images. You can install the package (`gimp-webp`) from this PPA:

> [ppa:george-edison55/webp [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/webp) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

The commands for doing this would be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/webp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp-webp
```

Once the package is installed, open up the Gimp and you will now be able to export images to the WebP format:

[image: Export dialog]

The package is currently available for Trusty, Utopic, Vivid, and Wily.

---

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the plugin.</sub>

Comment: Since v2.9 GIMP [comes with WebP support](https://www.gimp.org/news/2017/08/24/gimp-2-9-6-released/#webp-support) (thanks to Nathan and others)

Answer (score 2):

### 16.04 Fixed

Since 16.04 `imagemagick` (or `convert`) does support `webp`, although it delegates to webp, so you need to install webp.

```
sudo apt-get install webp
```

But importantly things like `convert img.png img.webp` do work now.

Before 16.04 `convert` simply gave a png or jpg as output. The result wasn't a webp format. (You probably got bigger filesizes because it converted jpg with default (higher) quality)

### Thumbnails:

```
display 'vid:*.webp'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [webp](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/webp) package in Software Center by which you can convert GIF to WebP via commandline.

Also there's a paint for KDE, [KolourPaint](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/kolourpaint4), which can save images as WebP.

Answer (score 0):

### Achieved using CLI

###### Windows:

```
> for /R . %I in (*.jpg) do ( cwebp.exe %I -o %~fnI.webp )
```

###### Linux / macOS:

```
$ for F in *.jpg; do cwebp $F -o `basename ${F%.jpg}`.webp; done
```

**Note**: replace .jpg with .png if PNG is what you are dealing with.

*Source*: [Google Devs FAQs](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/faq#how_can_i_convert_my_personal_images_files_to_webp)